# Is there a special method in React that updates DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello I am making a flashcard app in React and I am trying to switch in between cards, but they don't update until I switch the card over.

I have tried setting the index currentCard to state instead of globally, but I had some problems implementing that. I also tried this.forceUpdate(), but that either came out undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// variables
let currentCard = 0;
```

This is where I get the cards from:

```
const mockData = [
  {
    front: "Hello",
    back: "Dobrý den"
  },
  {
    front: "How are you?",
    back: "Jak se máš?"
  },
  {
    front: "I'm fine",
    back: "Mám se dobře"
  }

];

class LeftArrow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isClicked: false};
  }

  render(){
    //checks it so it can't be less than zero
    return(
      <button
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={() => this.props.onCardChange('LEFT')}
      >&lt;</button>
    )
  }
}

class RightArrow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isClicked: false};
  }

  render(){
    // checks it so it isn't more than the length of array
    // checks if card has
    return(
      <button
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={() => this.props.onCardChange('RIGHT')}
      >
      &gt;
      </button>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // helps toggle between the front face and the back
    this.state = {
      isFront: true,
    };
  }
```

This is the method I am using when someone clicks on the arrow:

```
  handleCardChange(direction) {
    if(direction === 'RIGHT'){
      console.log(direction);
      if(currentCard < mockData.length - 1){
        currentCard += 1;
      } else if (currentCard == mockData.length - 1) {
        currentCard = 0;
      }
    }

    if (direction === 'LEFT') {
      if (currentCard > 0) {
        currentCard -= 1;
      } else if (currentCard == 0) {
        currentCard = mockData.length - 1;
      }
    }
  }

  render(){
    // if clicked, isFront changes to the opposite
    // if isFront is true, show front, if not, show back
    console.log(this.state.wasTurned, currentCard);
    return (
      // , wasTurned: !this.state.wasTurned
      <div className="App">
        <div
        className="Card"
        onClick={() => this.setState({
          isFront: !this.state.isFront,
          wasTurned: true
        })}
        >
          {this.state.isFront ? mockData[currentCard].front : mockData[currentCard].back}
        </div>
        <div className="arrow_panel">
          <LeftArrow onCardChange={this.handleCardChange}/><RightArrow onCardChange={this.handleCardChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

I expected the card would automatically update itself, therefore when I would click the arrow it would show the front/back of the next card, but instead you have to click on the card again to see the next card. Thank you so much for just reading to this point and taking precious time from your busy day just to help me.

```js
// variables
let currentCard = 0;
const mockData = [
  {
    front: "Hello",
    back: "Dobrý den"
  },
  {
    front: "How are you?",
    back: "Jak se máš?"
  },
  {
    front: "I'm fine",
    back: "Mám se dobře"
  }

];

class LeftArrow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isClicked: false};
  }

  render(){
    //checks it so it can't be less than zero
    return(
      <button
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={() => this.props.onCardChange('LEFT')}
      >&lt;</button>
    )
  }
}

class RightArrow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isClicked: false};
  }

  render(){
    // checks it so it isn't more than the length of array
    // checks if card has
    return(
      <button
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={() => this.props.onCardChange('RIGHT')}
      >
      &gt;
      </button>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // helps toggle between the front face and the back
    this.state = {
      isFront: true,
    };
  }

  handleCardChange(direction) {
    if(direction === 'RIGHT'){
      console.log(direction);
      if(currentCard < mockData.length - 1){
        currentCard += 1;
      } else if (currentCard == mockData.length - 1) {
        currentCard = 0;
      }
    }

    if (direction === 'LEFT') {
      if (currentCard > 0) {
        currentCard -= 1;
      } else if (currentCard == 0) {
        currentCard = mockData.length - 1;
      }
    }
  }

  render(){
    // if clicked, isFront changes to the opposite
    // if isFront is true, show front, if not, show back
    console.log(this.state.wasTurned, currentCard);
    return (
      // , wasTurned: !this.state.wasTurned
      <div className="App">
        <div
        className="Card"
        onClick={() => this.setState({
          isFront: !this.state.isFront,
          wasTurned: true
        })}
        >
          {this.state.isFront ? mockData[currentCard].front : mockData[currentCard].back}
        </div>
        <div className="arrow_panel">
          <LeftArrow onCardChange={this.handleCardChange}/><RightArrow onCardChange={this.handleCardChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.Card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.arrow_panel button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you narrow down your post a little to only include the code that is relevant to your question? This might be a bit overwhelming for many to go through...

Comment: `setState` https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: you update the component's state data with the `setState()` component method. updating a component's state this way will re-render the DOM for that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put mockData and currentCard in state of the `Card` component and `handleCardChange` should update the state with `this.setState({})`.

```
const mockData = [
  {
    front: "Hello",
    back: "Dobrý den"
  },
  {
    front: "How are you?",
    back: "Jak se máš?"
  },
  {
    front: "I'm fine",
    back: "Mám se dobře"
  }
];

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // helps toggle between the front face and the back
    this.state = {
      isFront: true
      currentCard: 0,
      mockData,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setState

```
this.setState({someState: "someNewState"})
```